# Why is numpy slower than for loop

Tags: python, numpy, performance, for-loop, scipy

**Update:** this feature is now in `sciPy.stats.qmc.discrepancy` and was ported to Cython and also parallelised.

---

I have a function using some for loops and I wanted to improve the speed using numpy. But this seems not to do the trick as the bumpy version appears to be 2 times slower. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import timeit

def func():
    sample = np.random.random_sample((100, 2))
    
    disc1 = 0
    disc2 = 0
    n_sample = len(sample)
    dim = sample.shape[1]

    for i in range(n_sample):
        prod = 1
        for k in range(dim):
            sub = np.abs(sample[i, k] - 0.5)
            prod *= 1 + 0.5 * sub - 0.5 * sub ** 2
    
        disc1 += prod

    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_sample), range(n_sample)):
        prod = 1
        for k in range(dim):
            a = 0.5 * np.abs(sample[i, k] - 0.5)
            b = 0.5 * np.abs(sample[j, k] - 0.5)
            c = 0.5 * np.abs(sample[i, k] - sample[j, k])
            prod *= 1 + a + b - c
        disc2 += prod

    c2 = (13 / 12) ** dim - 2 / n_sample * disc1 + 1 / (n_sample ** 2) * disc2


def func_numpy():
    sample = np.random.random_sample((100, 2))

    disc1 = 0
    disc2 = 0
    n_sample = len(sample)
    dim = sample.shape[1]

    disc1 = np.sum(np.prod(1 + 0.5 * np.abs(sample - 0.5) - 0.5 * np.abs(sample - 0.5) ** 2, axis=1))
    
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_sample), range(n_sample)):
        disc2 += np.prod(1 + 0.5 * np.abs(sample[i] - 0.5) + 0.5 * np.abs(sample[j] - 0.5) - 0.5 * np.abs(sample[i] - sample[j]))
    
    c2 = (13 / 12) ** dim - 2 / n_sample * disc1 + 1 / (n_sample ** 2) * disc2


print('Normal function time: ' , timeit.repeat('func()', number=20, repeat=5, setup="from __main__ import func"))
print('numpy function time: ', timeit.repeat('func_numpy()', number=20, repeat=5, setup="from __main__ import func_numpy"))
```

The timing output is:

```
Normal function time:  [2.831496894999873, 2.832342429959681, 2.8009242500411347, 2.8075121529982425, 2.824807019031141]
numpy function time:  [5.154757721000351, 5.2011515340418555, 5.148996959964279, 5.095560318033677, 5.125199959962629]
```

What am I missing here? I know that the bottleneck is the itertools part because I have a 100x100x2 loop instead of a 100x2 loop before.
Do you see another way to do that?

Comment: Have you checked that there are no unwanted broadcast operations?

Comment: How can I check that exactly?

Comment: You could print `x.shape` to ensure that the operations are done properly and the output is of the expected shape/size.

Comment: Try profiling your code and see where the bottleneck is. For example in your numpy version, you can compute `np.abs(sample - 0.5)` once and re-use it instead of computing it twice...

Comment: There's a lot that could be improved in each version. It really doesn't make sense to compare such not-optimal solutions. Try to optimize each individually before comparing them against each other.

Comment: That itertools.product doesn't seem the most numpy friendly thing to do. You're going in and out numpy paying overhead and who knows what else.

Comment: Your itertools loop generates 100*100 steps, while the `dim` loop is only 2 steps.  So you aren't making any significant use of `numpy` array fuctionality.

Comment: Indeed it is the itertools loop that is the botleneck. @MSeifert could you elaborate? I though these two were OK...

Comment: @sirfz I did it and it is obviously the itertool loop that is doing all the job. I have tried your suggestion (np.abs) with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NumPy, one must look to vectorize things and we could certainly do  so here.

Taking a closer look at the loop portion, we are iterating along the first axis of the input data `samples` twice with that loop startup :

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_sample), range(n_sample)):
```

We could convert these iterations into vectorized operations, once we let [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) handle those.

Now, to have a fully vectorized solution, we would need a lot more memory space, specifically `(N,N,M)`, where `(N,M)` is the shape of the input data.

Another noticeable aspect here is that at each iteration, we aren't doing a lot of work, as we are performing operation on each row and each row contains only `2` elements for the given sample. So, the idea that comes out is that we could run a loop along `M`, such that at each iteration, we would compute the `prod` and accumulate. Thus, for the given sample, its just two loop iterations.

Getting out of the loop, we would have the accumulated `prod`, that just needs summation for `disc2` as the final output.

Here's an implementation to fulfil the above mentioned ideas -

```
prod_arr = 1
for i in range(sample.shape[1]):
    si = sample[:,i]
    prod_arr *= 1 + 0.5 * np.abs(si[:,None] - 0.5) + 0.5 * np.abs(si - 0.5) - \
                                    0.5 * np.abs(si[:,None] - si)
disc2 = prod_arr.sum()
```

**Runtime test**

The stripped down version of the loopy portion from the original approach and the modified versions as approaches are listed below :

```
def org_app(sample):
    disc2 = 0
    n_sample = len(sample)
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_sample), range(n_sample)):
        disc2 += np.prod(1 + 0.5 * np.abs(sample[i] - 0.5) + 0.5 * \
            np.abs(sample[j] - 0.5) - 0.5 * np.abs(sample[i] - sample[j]))
    return disc2


def mod_app(sample):
    prod_arr = 1
    for i in range(sample.shape[1]):
        si = sample[:,i]
        prod_arr *= 1 + 0.5 * np.abs(si[:,None] - 0.5) + 0.5 * np.abs(si - 0.5) - \
                                        0.5 * np.abs(si[:,None] - si)
    disc2 = prod_arr.sum()
    return disc2
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [10]: sample = np.random.random_sample((100, 2))

In [11]: org_app(sample)
Out[11]: 11934.878683659041

In [12]: mod_app(sample)
Out[12]: 11934.878683659068

In [14]: %timeit org_app(sample)
10 loops, best of 3: 84.4 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit mod_app(sample)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.6 µs per loop
```

About **`900x`** speedup! Well this should be motivating enough, hopefully to look to vectorize things whenever possible.

Comment: Generally better to include `()` instead of using backslashes when using multiline expressions.

Comment: @MSeifert Line wrapping where?

Comment: It's removing the backslashes from my comments. But I meant the line that starts with: `prod_arr *= 1 + 0.5 * ...`

Comment: @MSeifert Doesn't allow me to avoid backslash on my Spyder IDE. An IDE thing?

Comment: @Divakar Strange, doesn't the version I included in my answer work (I used the `()` without backslash. My IDE hates backslashes at the end of lines. :D

Comment: If anyone is reading this now: I pushed the feature is in `scipy.stats.qmc.discrepancy`. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments your solutions are not really optimal and it doesn't really make sense to compare not-ideal approaches.

For one thing iterating or indexing single elements of a NumPy array is really slow. I recently answered a question including a lot of details (if you're interested you might have a look at it: ["convert np array to a set takes too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226069/5393381)). So the Python approach could be faster simply by converting the `array` to a `list`:

```
def func():
    sample = np.random.random_sample((100, 2))
    disc1 = 0
    n_sample = len(sample)
    dim = sample.shape[1]
    sample = sample.tolist()  # converted to list

    for i in range(n_sample):
        prod = 1
        for item in sample[i]:
            sub = abs(item - 0.5)
            prod *= 1 + 0.5 * sub - 0.5 * sub ** 2
        disc1 += prod

    disc2 = 0
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_sample), range(n_sample)):
        prod = 1
        for k in range(dim):
            a = 0.5 * abs(sample[i][k] - 0.5)
            b = 0.5 * abs(sample[j][k] - 0.5)
            c = 0.5 * abs(sample[i][k] - sample[j][k])
            prod *= 1 + a + b - c
        disc2 += prod

    c2 = (13 / 12) ** dim - 2 / n_sample * disc1 + 1 / (n_sample ** 2) * disc2
```

I also replaced the `np.abs` calls with normal `abs`. The normal `abs` has a lower overhead! And also changed some other parts. In the end this is more than 10-20 times faster than your original "normal" approach.

I didn't have time to check the NumPy approach yet and @Divarkar already included a really good and optimized approach. Comparing the two approaches:

```
def func_numpy():
    sample = np.random.random_sample((100, 2))

    disc1 = 0
    disc2 = 0
    n_sample = len(sample)
    dim = sample.shape[1]

    disc1 = np.sum(np.prod(1 + 
                           0.5 * np.abs(sample - 0.5) - 
                           0.5 * np.abs(sample - 0.5) ** 2, 
                           axis=1))

    prod_arr = 1
    for i in range(sample.shape[1]):
        s0 = sample[:,i]
        prod_arr *= (1 + 
                     0.5 * np.abs(s0[:,None] - 0.5) + 
                     0.5 * np.abs(s0 - 0.5) - 
                     0.5 * np.abs(s0[:,None] - s0))
    disc2 = prod_arr.sum()

    c2 = (13 / 12) ** dim - 2 / n_sample * disc1 + 1 / (n_sample ** 2) * disc2


print('Normal function time: ' , 
      timeit.repeat('func()', number=20, repeat=3, setup="from __main__ import func"))
# Normal function time:  [1.4846746248249474, 1.5018398493266432, 1.5476674017127152]
print('numpy function time: ', 
      timeit.repeat('func_numpy()', number=20, repeat=3, setup="from __main__ import func_numpy"))
# numpy function time:  [0.020140038561976326, 0.016502230831292763, 0.016452520269695015]
```

So an optimized NumPy approach can definetly beat an "optimized" Python approach. It's almost 100 times faster. In case you want it even faster you could use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) on a slightly modified version of the pure python code:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def func_numba():
    sample = np.random.random_sample((100, 2))
    disc1 = 0
    n_sample = len(sample)
    dim = sample.shape[1]

    for i in range(n_sample):
        prod = 1
        for item in sample[i]:
            sub = abs(item - 0.5)
            prod *= 1 + 0.5 * sub - 0.5 * sub ** 2
        disc1 += prod

    disc2 = 0
    for i in range(n_sample):
        for j in range(n_sample):
            prod = 1
            for k in range(dim):
                a = 0.5 * abs(sample[i,k] - 0.5)
                b = 0.5 * abs(sample[j,k] - 0.5)
                c = 0.5 * abs(sample[i,k] - sample[j,k])
                prod *= 1 + a + b - c
            disc2 += prod

    return (13 / 12) ** dim - 2 / n_sample * disc1 + 1 / (n_sample ** 2) * disc2

func_numba()


print('numba function time: ' , 
      timeit.repeat('func_numba()', number=20, repeat=3, setup="from __main__ import func_numba"))
# numba function time:  [0.003022848984983284, 0.0030429566279508435, 0.004060626777572907]
```

That's almost a factor 8-10 faster than the NumPy approach.

Comment: @Y0da I also included an additional approach and timed it against Divarkars solution.

Comment: I cannot vote for two answers but yours is also definitely worth looking at! Thanks for the numba approach.

Comment: @Y0da You can vote on both answers - but you can only **accept** one. And Divarkars answer definetly deserves the **accept**. :)

Comment: Numba the last resort huh! ;)

Comment: I'm tired of thinking about broadcasting stuff and worrying about `MemoryError`s - so Numba, Cython or (if possible) numexpr are in most cases much handier than pure-NumPy :) Unfortunatly Cython is not really appropriate on StackOverflow because the compilation is complicated (if one doesn't use IPythons magic `%%cython`).

Comment: @MSeifert With the broadcasting, why numba is faster? I though that behind numpy it was C so there should be no speedup for me.

Comment: @Y0da Numba uses LLVM to compile the code, so the loops are basically at C speed and it doesn't use python types but C types which makes the arithmetic as fast as if you would use NumPy. It's faster because it doesn't create temporary arrays (each operation on a numpy array like `array + 2` creates a new array) and it avoids the excessive memory use that broadcasting needs (broadcasting creates a huge intermediate array).

Comment: However numba doesn't support all (in fact it only supports a few) python and numpy operations and it requires a lot of trial and error to actually make an operation as fast as possible. In this case it's quite easy but generally it can be quite hard to find a numba implementation that is actually (much) faster than NumPy.