# How to speed up nested for loops with function call in python 3?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I have been trying to make 3D drawing library for python 3, using Pygame. I want to use Z-Buffer so I need to call function for each pixel that should be drawn. Problem is that drawing 100x100 pixel rectangle takes more than 1 millisecond. 
Drawing function for rectangle is nested loop with function call and it can be simplified to this code to show the biggest bottleneck:

```
def another_function():
    pass

def test_function():
    for j in range(100):
        for k in range(100):
            another_function()
```

Function another_function() which does nothing is called 10000 times total. When I measured execution time, timeit has shown that test_function() takes 1.09 millisecond. This is too long because it is necessary to draw multiple rectangles and to achieve 60 frames per second, one frame must take less than 17 milliseconds.

I tried searching for solutions but I have been unable to find any way to increase speed of nested for loops with function calls besides using PyPy and Cython.

Additional information: I am using Python 3.5.2 with Windows 10 64-bit as OS. I didn't find any installer for PyPy for Windows and Cython has problem when compiling modules converted to .c so I can't use it.

Comment: do your function inline?

Comment: The PyPy for windows can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/

Comment: _When your Python has performance trouble / your loops and calls run too slowly / remember the old wisdom: / **write in C**!_

Comment: The loops aren't what's killing you. The function call is. An easy way to tell that is comment out the function call and then time it.

Comment: @zwer Using C isn't solution because I have issue with compiler (I think that more exactly with linker). This issue is preventing me from using Cython.

Comment: @Alven - trust me, fixing your C environment is a far, **far** easier task than forcing Python to do something it was never designed for.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what you are actually doing into `another_function()`. If you can use some *numpy* [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you can achieve some C speed. Indeed, even with the latest improvements in python 3.6, `for` loops are still to avoid for performance reasons.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422762/6522112) for example. There is a 900X performance boost over a loop when *numpy* is properly used.

Also, you did not mentioned it but you can go with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) and its *just in time* compiler. This is particularly well suited in case of pure python loops.